# how can i link my mobile application with web service?

Tags: php, android, web-hosting

I have mobile app with web service in bluehost web hosting
just planned a transfer to an another web hosting , how can it be possible to link my app with the same web service in my new web hosting

Comment: ? what? I don't really get what you're asking, but if your mobile app depends on an api reached with a certain url it doesn't matter to which  this url leads the app.

Comment: if using the uri not the IP ther should be nothing to change

Comment: If you're using the same program, just transfer all your files (including your database) and when the DNS changes you should be all good.  Unless you specified your host via IP, in which case you need to change the IP in the client.

Answer (score 0):

we need more information to can help you Mohammed

bu if you need convert your old IP to new IP you can edit this by your source code for your app

Comment: i am not a developer ,i have a mobile app in play store which store information in bluehost web hosting , i need to transfer files and database to hostgator ,what should i do after i upload my files to hostgator

Comment: There is nobody can help you here , you need any developer to make it for you